# python pandas TypeError: int object not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting this TypeError that pops up in random places when using python pandas and it makes no sense to me at all.

When using

```
if len(pd.unique(data["Adj Close"])) > 100:
```

I get the error

```
if len(pd.unique(data["Adj Close"])) > 100:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

which presumably means data["Adj Close"] is an int.

But when I do

```
if pd.unique(data["Adj Close"]) > 100:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

it tells me that data["Adj Close"] is now an array, which is what it should be.

This is the column printed out

```
0      24.280519
1      24.280519
2      24.379221
3      23.984415
4      26.057142
         ...    
120    25.799999
121    26.799999
122    27.000000
123    27.200001
124    27.700001
Name: Adj Close, Length: 125, dtype: float64
```

Also, earlier I tried to use

```
len(df.columns)
```

to count the amount of columns in a dataframe and again i get this exact TypeError.

I don't see how any of these return an int object.

Comment: Can also use `df.shape[1]` to get the number of columns.

Comment: For this `len(pd.unique(data["Adj Close"]))`, this can be used `data["Adj Close"].unique().size`.

Comment: Are you using `len` someplace as a variable name?

Comment: I hope you are not using "len" as a variable name somewhere else

Comment: To expand @MattDMo comment; if `len` has been assigned an integer value in previous lines, the builtin `len()` function, essentially no longer exists; as it’s now a numeric value rather than a function - hence the error.

Comment: @MattDMo YES thank you! I can't believe I just wasted an hour because I was stupid enough to use len as a variable name. Thank you!! And everyone else who answered so quickly as well!

Comment: Use a linter to help you catch mistakes like this faster!  :)